# Detect change in aria-labelledby value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, wai-aria

How can I detect using jquery ,  whether a label which is basically and anchor tag with aria is being toggled UP and DOWN (ie its aria-labelledby is changing to UP and DOWN)

```
<a href="#" class="ui-slider-updownhandle" data-corners="true" data-wrappers="span" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="up" aria-valuetext="Up" title="Up" aria-labelledby="label-1" style="left: 0%;"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span></span></a>
```

Comment: Take a look at [`attrchange` jQuery plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this and get current value of the slider for mobile jquery

```
$($('.ui-slider-track.ui-shadow-inset.ui-bar-c.ui-corner-all').children()[1]).attr('aria-valuenow')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can actively "monitor" an element to note a change, that is cross browser. If you "know" when the element is triggered via an event handler or something, of course you can just get the `attr`.

```
 if( jQuery('.ui-slider-updownhandle').attr('aria-labelledby') === "UP" ){
   // do something.
 }
```

The Jaws browser knows "when content is updated" when you apply an attribute onto the element. Is that what you are referring to?

I see you have aria-labelledby as `label-1`, so not sure what you mean when you say "UP" or "DOWN".

Please try this, I have the link not firing with `preventDefault()`, but that is so you can see the event firing off.

```
 $('.ui-slider-updownhandle').bind('click', function(e){
      //just grabbing some values to show.
      console.log($(this).attr('aria-valuetext'), $(this).attr('aria-labelledby'));
      e.preventDefault();
 })
```

I apologize if I am off base in terms of what you need. Truth be told, I'm not entirely sure what you need, so figuring I'll start with an assumption :-)

note: if you have issue with `attr`, try `prop` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ 
   aria:function(arrib,NewVal){
     return (NewVal) ? jQuery(this).attr("aria-"+arrib,NewVal) : jQuery(this).attr("aria-"+arrib);
 }

});
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Please format your code correctly and consider adding context to your answer.